# Casting issue while returning value in method in EF4.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to load employees using Entity Framework.
The method is supposed to return employee list.

It' s giving this error:

```
Cannot implicit convert....<Class names and methods>.... An Explicit conversion exists.
```

I think the problem is related to casting.

Please check below code.

```
    public List<Employee> LoadEmployees()
     {
         try
         {
             EMployeeDB1Entities EE = new EMployeeDB1Entities();
             var Employees = EE.Employees.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("T"));
             return Employees;

         }
         catch
         {
             return null;
         }

     }
```

Comment: Is it a compile time or runtime error?

Answer (score 1):

```
var Employees = EE.Employees.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("T")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to:

```
return Employees.ToList();
```

Also do note that this is the `ToList()` method that actually triggers the database query.

`EE.Employees.Where(....)` doesn't query the database. The DB is queried **when the result of the `Where()` is enumerated**, which is what `.ToList()` does.

---

> Thanks it works...one more issue, suppose if I want to bind above list
>   to grid then how can I bind ?

Assuming you're using WPF or Silverlight:
To bind the result of your query on a datagrid, you could expose a public property of type [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).
This collection accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` object as constructor.
You can write:

```
var myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(this.LoadEmployees());
```

Then bind the [`ItemSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.itemssource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of your datagrid to your collection.

If you have more problems using bindings, I recommend you to ask another question, because the subject is quite different.

Comment: Thanks it works...one more issue, suppose if I want to bind above list to grid then how can I bind ?